# Collect stream to generic Collection

Tags: java, generics, collections, java-stream

Say I want to make a simple method which takes in a collection and cuts the number of its elements:

```
    public static <T extends Collection<?>> T limit(T collection, long limit){
        return collection.stream().limit(limit).collect(Collectors.toCollection(???));
    }
```

Is it possible to collect it back to a collection of the generic type?

Comment: No. There’s no even a guaranty that it is possible to construct a collection of the same type, in general. Just think about what should happen when someone passes [`someMap.values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#values()) to your method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no sane (*) way to create a new collection of the generic type `T` inside `limit`. Your best bet is to pass a factory for creating that type into the `limit` function:

```
public static <E, T extends Collection<E>> T limit(T collection, long limit, Supplier<T> factory) {
    return collection.stream()
        .limit(limit)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(factory));
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var limited = limit(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, ArrayList::new);
```

(*) You could resort to [using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74473721/402428), but that would not work with all collection types and thus defeat the purpose of genericity.

Comment: Note that in your example, `limited` will have the type `List` rather than `ArrayList`, as the first argument is not an `ArrayList`. Requiring the first argument to be of the same type, is an unnecessary restriction anyway; you can convert any `Collection<E>` to `T` with this method if you just declare the first parameter that way.

Comment: I guess it does the trick, even though some more code is required, could be useful for some more complicated pipelines.

Answer (score 2):

***Disclaimer:** It wouldn't work in any scenario. For instance, it would be no possible to constructusing this code [*unmodifiable collections*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/core/creating-immutable-lists-sets-and-maps.html#GUID-DD066F67-9C9B-444E-A3CB-820503735951) like `ListN`, `SetN`, views of over collections (e.g. `sublist()`), synchronized collections, with lists created via `Collections.nCopies`, `Arrays.asList()`, and with `EnumSet` since it has no default constructor.*

To provide an empty collection in the Collector of the stream, we can make use of reflection to try to get access to the *no-args* constructor of the Collection.

```
public static <T> Collection<T> limit(Collection<T> collection, long limit) {
    
    Class<?> c = collection.getClass();
    
    return collection.stream()
        .limit(limit)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(
            () -> (Collection<T>) getCollectionInstance(c)
        ));
}

public static Collection<?> getCollectionInstance(Class<?> c) {
        try {
            return (Collection<?>) c.getConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException |
                 InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Deque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Set.of("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"));

    Collection<Integer> dequeCopy = limit(deque, 3);
    Collection<String> setCopy = limit(set, 3);

    System.out.println(dequeCopy.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    System.out.println(dequeCopy);
    
    System.out.println(setCopy.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    System.out.println(setCopy);
}
```

*Output:*

```
java.util.ArrayDeque
[1, 2, 3]
java.util.HashSet
[A, B, C]
```

Comment: Not only does this not work with unmodifiable collections, it also doesn’t work with `EnumSet`, synchronized collections, checked collections, `Arrays.asList`, sublists, as well as `keySet()`, `entrySet()`, and `values()` from a `Map`. Even with `TreeSet` which happens to have a default constructor, there’s some chance that it will not do the right thing, i.e. if the source set has a comparator. And what’s this hack worth anyway, when you change the return type to `Collection` instead of the source type?

Comment: @Holger You're right, my bad, there's no difference. Updated the answer.

Comment: Yes , I have tried something with reflection too, but it was more an exercise than a practical solution. Thanks for clarifying.